# Trigger input change on website using Angular with Chrome Extension content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, input, content-script

I'm creating a content-script which will populate 
https://www.moneysupermarket.com/shop/car-insurance/questionset/#?step=highimpactquestions
with predefined data.

But I have problem with first step, the first field on the page, registration number.

I'm using jQuery inside my script, and I can set input's value to what I want using

```
 $('input#regnumber').val(data['car_reg'])
```

But when I simulate click on find car button it seems like for website that field is empty, as 'Please enter a registration number' warning appears instead of showing car info.

I looked through the code, and saw that website uses angular, so I guess it has something to do with its binding.

I tried triggering change,keyup,input events on the `$('input#regnumber')` but it doesn't change anything.

EDIT:
Also tried with

```
$('input#regnumber').val(data['car_reg']).dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));
```

without success

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS inputs use an `ng-model` directive to connect an input with the model:

```
<input id="regnumber" type="text" ng-model="formData.item" />
```

To set the model from outside the framework use:

```
var elem = $('input#regnumber');
var scope = angular.element(elem).scope();

scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.formData.item = value;
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)
- [AngularJS scope API Reference ($apply)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope (Integration with the Browser Event Loop)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

[image]

Comment: I get this error: ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You are getting validation error, because maybe the value of data['car_reg'] is undefined. If the data is an array of objects, then use like data[0].car_reg. Use console to verify the value.

Comment: No, value of regnumber field gets set successfully to the data['car_reg'], it's just that angular doesn't register it.
You can try with any string instead of data['car_reg']

Answer (score 0):

I found a way finally.. this is what I did in my background script for the tab where this page is loaded:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { 'file': '/jquery-2.2.4.min.js', 'runAt': 'document_start' })
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { 'file': '/angular.min.js' })
    setTimeout(function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { 'code': 'angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();' });
        setTimeout(function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { 'file': '/jquery-2.2.4.min.js' });
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { 'file': '/formfiller.js' })
        }, 5000);
    }, 5000);
}, 8000)
```

And in my `formfiller.js` I do this in order to fill that field:

```
 var scrpt = document.createElement('script');

    scrpt.innerText = "var scp = angular.element($('#regnumber')).scope();scp.regnumber = '12345';scp.$apply(); $('.car-registration__button').click();"

    document.head.appendChild(scrpt);

    scrpt.onload = function() {
        scrpt.parentNode.removeChild(scrpt);
    };
```

Comment: The "angular not defined" error on the other answer is because the content script executed in an "isolated world" from angular.  This approach gets around that by loading angular into the same isolated world.  6 years later, it is possible to execute a script within the same world, so you might be able to have the other answer work by setting the [ExecutionWorld](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ExecutionWorld) to "MAIN".